# Very difficult Bayes, smokers problem

Tags: probability, problem-solving, bayesian, bayes-theorem

50% of people don't smoke, 20% are light smokers & 30% are heavy smokers.

Heavy smokers are twice as likely to die prematurely as light smokers, light smokers are twice as likely to die prematurely as nonsmokers.

What's the probability of being a heavy smoker given person died prematurely?

I'm sure this would be a Bayes' theorem problem, but I can't figure out how to find the probability of deaths.

Comment: I'm assuming that some qualification like "of cancer" is missing, because every human is equally likely to die, i.e. with probability 1.

Comment: It doesn't matter how much people smoke or not. And no need for Bayes here. The answer is simply $4/7$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, I think that was a coincidence. If you try 60% NS, 30% LS, and 10% HS, it works out to $P(\mathrm{HS}|\mathrm{D}) = 0.25$

Comment: Immortality is not precluded in the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> heavy smokers are twice as likely to die as light smokers, light smokers are twice as likely to die as nonsmokers

that is a succession of frequencies like

$$1;2;4$$

for non smokers, light smokers and heavy smokers that means a probability to die of

$$\left\{\frac{1}{1+2+4};\frac{2}{1+2+4};\frac{4}{1+2+4}   \right\}=\left\{\frac{1}{7};\frac{2}{7};\frac{4}{7}   \right\}$$

respectively...the rest is a simply Bayes' Theorem example.

Thus, concluding,

$$\mathbb{P}[HS|D]=\frac{0.3\times\frac{4}{7}}{0.5\times\frac{1}{7}+0.2\times\frac{2}{7}+0.3\times\frac{4}{7}}\approx 0.57$$

Comment: Why do the probabilities need to sum to 1? Why can't the probabilities be $\frac{1}{100},\frac{2}{100},\frac{4}{100}$?

Comment: @Joe : because the probability for a person to die is, at present, 100%

Comment: Yes, so light smokers are not twice as likely to die as nonsmokers, since they both have a 100% chance of dying.

Comment: @Joe Fully agree with you. Especially assuming that the probability of anyone to die is $1$, then they should sum to $3$. Otherwise, they can a priori sum to any number in $[0,3]$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ denote 'die because of some reason such as cancer' as @Joe indicates this is needed since everyone will die with probability $1$. Let $NS$, $L$ and $H$ denote not smoker, light smoker and heavy smoker respectively. Then we have that $P(D|H)=2P(D|L) = 4P(D|NS)$ . We have that $P(NS) = 0.5$, $P(L) = 0.2$ and $P(H)=0.3$.

Then by Bayes' theorem we find that e.g. $P(H|D) = P(D|H)P(H)/P(D)$. Using this and the above we find that by dividing probabilities:

\begin{align}
\frac{P(H|D)}{P(L|D)} &= \frac{P(H)}{P(L)} \frac{P(D|H)}{P(D|L)} = (0.3/0.2)\cdot 2 = 3.
\end{align}

Similarly, it follows that:

\begin{align}
P(L|D) &= 0.8 P(NS|D),\\
P(H|D) &= 1.6 P(NS|D). \\
\end{align}

It holds that $P(L|D) + P(H|D) + P(NS|D) = 1$ (because $L,H,NS$ form a partition of all the people). Hence it follows that $P(H|D)(1+1/3 + 1/(2.4)) = 1 \implies P(H|D) \approx 0.57.$

Answer (score 0):

This question deals strictly with the subspace of the dead.  It can be solved quite simply, yet subtly, in this manner:

In the subspace of the dead:

```
       P(non smoke) + P(light smoke) + P(heavy smoke) = 1
```

Let us rename thusly:

```
       P(N) + P(L) + P(H) = 1               (1)
```

We are supplied the additional linearly independent information that:

```
       P(L) = 2 * P(N)                      (2)
       P(H) = 2 * P(L)                      (3)
```

Substitute (2) into (3):

```
       P(H) = 2 * (2 * P(N))
       P(H) = 4 * P(N)                      (4)
```

We can now rewrite equation (1) entirely in terms of P(N) using (2) and (4):

```
       P(N) + (2 * P(N)) + (4 * P(N)) = 1
       7 * P(N) = 1
       P(N) = 1/7                           (5)
```

Substitute (5) in to (4):

```
       P(H) = 4 * (1/7)
       P(H) = 4/7
```

Complete.

Comment: The labels and meanings of probabilities you talk about in your post do not match the problem statement.  $\frac{4}{7}$ is indeed an important number here in this problem, but it is not "*The probability of being a heavy smoker*" nor is it "*The probability of being a dead heavy smoker*" etc...  As such, you ended the problem far too early before having gotten to the question the original problem statement is actually asking about.

Comment: @JMoravitz please read the answer more closely before commenting.
"In the subspace of the dead" prefaces the answer.
Thus, P(H), as defined in my answer, is the original question.
I'll leave it to you as an exercise to verify that 4/7 ~= 0.57, which is the correct answer. 
4/7 is a better answer than any of the other solutions since it is an exact fraction rather than a truncated decimal, the approximate notation notwithstanding.
The fact that the other rather overwrought methods could not yield the exact fraction is unfortunate.

Comment: Where did you use that 50% don't smoke, or that 20% are light smokers and 30% heavy smokers?  Since these don't appear in your answer it can't be arrived at correctly.

Comment: In a world where 99.9999999999% of people are non-smokers, and a trivial amount are light and heavy smokers, and an event occurs causing people to die such that the probability of death given the person is a light smoker is twice the probability of the probability of death given the person is a non-smoker... we should still expect due to the sheer difference in numbers that given a person died that they should still be a non-smoker.  It may so happen to be a coincidence that the correct answer matches the answer you arrived at but that does not make your answer correct when considering method

Comment: The other solution you post at a glance appears correct, but as already mentioned I find this answer incorrect.  It wasn't done "efficiently," it was done incorrectly.  As for the worth of the other answer, I do not see it adding any extra clarity over the two other already present correct answers written by other people.

Comment: It follows from p(smoker) = p(nonsmoker), specific to the problem. I was taught it's best to answer the exact question asked as efficiently as possible. I posted a more general solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general solution than my shortcut one above.

Notation: "Heavy Smoker" = $HS$, "Light Smoker" = $LS$, "Non Smoker" = $NS$, "Smoker" = $S$ "Dead" = $D$.

The question asks to find $P(HS|D)$. Applying Bayes::
$$P(HS|D)=\frac{P(D|HS) * P(HS)}{P(D)}\tag{1}$$
From given information: $$P(D|LS)=2P(D|NS) $$ $$P(D|HS) = 2P(D|LS) = 4P(D|NS)$$ $$P(HS) = 0.3$$ $$P(LS) =0.2$$ $$P(NS) = 0.5$$ $$P(S) = 0.5$$
Continuing, we need $P(D)$.

Since smoker status partitions the space: $$P(D) = P(D|HS)P(HS) + P(D|LS)P(LS) + P(D|NS)P(NS)$$

Substitute in:$$P(D) = 4P(D|NS)0.3 + 2P(D|NS)0.2 + P(D|NS)0.5$$
$$P(D) = 2.1P(D|NS)\tag{2}$$

Plug (2) and other known information into (1):
$$P(HS|D) = \frac{4P(D|NS) * 0.3}{2.1P(D|NS)}$$
$$P(HS|D) = \frac{1.2P(D|NS)}{2.1P(D|NS)}$$
$$P(HS|D) = \frac{1.2}{2.1}$$
$$P(HS|D) = \frac{12}{21}$$
$$P(HS|D) = \frac{4}{7}$$